# Add an icon to LaTeX to open an internet link

Tags: urls, hyperlink, embedding, icon

I have seen this LaTeX document and in my opinion it is quite fancy. It is a "normal" document, but if I press the red icon, a YouTube link opens. Does any body hava an idea how this might work?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a combination of `graphicx` (to import the image) and the command `\href` from `hyperref` (to insert a hyperlink and customize its appearance).

The first argument of `\href` is the desired URL, the second is the text, or object, to be displayed in the document and to be made clickable. In our case, the object is an image imported via `\includegraphics`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}     % dummy text
\usepackage{graphicx}   % to import images
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}   % for hyperlinks
    % Option "hidelinks" to hide the bounding box; "colorlinks" works here too.

\begin{document}

\marginpar{%
\href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/633464}%
{\includegraphics[width=20pt]{sample.jpg}}%
}%
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

(In the generated PDF, the image is a clickable link to this page.)

[image: clickable image with link]

In general, you want to load `hyperref` last, after all other packages, for it to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an icon for external links, or a YouTube icon for a YouTube video or playlist in this case, along with the `\href{}{}` command to include URLs embedded within text.

```
\documentclass{article}
% Package with icons for URLs, or Internet links.
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
% Package for "\href{}{}" command to embed a URL within text.
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\ \\
\faYoutube \href{https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TpGMCQCWd4M}{System/Technology Co-Optimization} \\
\faLink\ \href{https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TpGMCQCWd4M}{System/Technology Co-Optimization} \\
\faExternalLink*\ \href{https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TpGMCQCWd4M}{System/Technology Co-Optimization}
\end{document}
```

This should give you the result that you are looking for:

- An icon for Internet links, or U.R.L.s.

  - in this case, an URL for a YouTube video
- Normal text, with an U.R.L. embedded by that text.

The example looks like this.

[image: Example of how the YouTube, Internet links, (external) URL icons should look like]

I have added space between the icon and text embedding the URL for clarity. Likewise, I used the initial `\ \\` to align all the text onto the same starting position/location on the x-axis.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!